# Bind text as html in facebook share tags in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook share button with

```
$scope.share = function(post){
  var x = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.title);
  console.log('x is : ',x, post.title);
FB.ui(
  {
      method: 'feed',
      name: $sce.trustAsHtml(post.title),
      link: 'http://www.example.com/',
      picture: 'http://www.example.com/14384178441.jpg',
      caption: 'Blog' ,
      description: $sce.trustAsHtml(post.desc),
      message: ''
  });
};
```

I was storing post.title and post.desc as htmlentites encoded in mysql and while retrieving and displaying these I was doing first hemlentited decode and then displaying the value as $sce.trustAsHtml(post.title).

But when I am doing $sce.trustAsHtml(post.title) in share function, when the dialog for the facebook share opens I still see the special characters. I want the name and description in facebook share  to be shown as just the simple text or as html just like $sce.trustAsHtml() does.